# Span parsing python

Tags: python, html, parsing

I am new user here. I got problem with parsing data via beautifullsoup(python). I have span like this:

```
<span class="kolesa-score-label cheaper">
    <span class="kolesa-score-label-on">на</span> 
    2.93%&nbsp;дешевле
</span>
```

I need to get 2.93

`deshevle = soup.find_all('span', class_='kolesa-score-label cheaper').text`

Is not working.

One more problem is that:

```
for div in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'row vw-item list-item blue a-elem'}):
    adv_id=str(div.find('a')['data-product-id'])
```

it is recording only last cycle. Why? Because I want to take it as list... already tried `adv_id=[]` and nothing changed

Comment: What does "Is not working" mean? Are you getting errors? If so, please post the full traceback. Are you getting other unexpected behaviour? If so, please specify what you expected and what goes wrong. I suspect that you're getting an `AttributeError` because `soup.find_all` returns a list, and lists obviously don't have the `text` attribute. As for the second piece of code, you need to learn [how lists work](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> adv_id=str(div.find('a')['data-product-id'])
> ```

try adv_id.append maybe? (after adv_id=[] ofc)

but if you want a list you should think like one and not use append at all:

adv_id = [str(div.find('a')['data-product-id']) for div in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'row vw-item list-item blue a-elem'})]

list comprehension:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

PS: no clue on your beautifullsoup, im just whoring some python reputation here

Comment: okay. what about span? how to get span text, where i have span inside of span?